# Symfony Form Collection with Entity gigantic load time

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony-forms

I'm using Symfony 2.8. I have a form **Sheet** which contains a collection of **SheetArticles**.
In this SheetArticleType, I want to get to the linked Article entity.

So the result buildForms look like the following:

**SheetType.php:**

```
$builder
        ->add('articles','collection',array(
            'type' => SheetArticleType::class,
            'by_reference'=> false,
            ));
```

**SheetArticleType:**

```
$builder
        ->add('article')
```

Although it's working (I can navigate through the entity in my twig with **vars.data** and get to whatever property of the Entity **Article** I want, it somehow take at least 16seconds to load the whole page (even with only 4 articles) and I have no idea of what take that long.

[image: Performance metrics from symfony dev mode]

Comment: The development profile shows much info about the performance - can you provide a screenshot of it? You should be able to see there what processes take extra long

Comment: I've edited with the screenshot. I also saw that it's the render of the blocks that take a lot of time. And it's the form_widget, which is 1.5s long to load..

Comment: I think that your `'article'` field is a select of Article from the database ? Maybe you have to much in this select..?

Comment: the 'article' is from an Entity in the database. But i didn't figured out how to import the article to get the whole value of it (to have the accessors basically). So I think i'll only get the information I want using Ajax.